# Android Split the white spaces to separate paragraph using regular expression?

Tags: android, regex, split, whitespace

I need to split the \n or \t or \s and other spaces of data to a paragraph using regular expression. I got the information from XML and need to display it using paragraph structure.

Any idea?

Comment: can you add the before and the desired after state?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

#### Code

```
String str = "foo\t bar\rboo far\nbaz";
String[] parts = str.split("\\s+");

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(parts));
```

#### Output

```
[foo, bar, boo, far, baz]
```